# Why are undeclared object properties not flagged as errors?

Tags: typescript

```
var opts: {n?: number; s?: string;};
opts = {n: 2};     // Ok
opts = {s: 'x'};   // Ok
opts = {};         // Ok
opts = {z: 3};     // Ok, but shouldn't this be an error?
```

I want the `opts` object to accept none or any of the declared
optional properties (but no others), but it accepts other undefined
properties i.e. the declaration is equivalent to `opts: {};`, is this 
a bug?

If it's not a bug how can you construct such a declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the beauty of TypeScript is that it is quite clever at deciding whether an object can be coerced into another type.

You declaration for `opts` actually has no requirements because both properties are optional, so any any object is compatible with this type. To be compatible, an object must contain all required properties - and in this case there are no required properties.

This is clearer if we look at an adjusted example that does require a property:

```
var opts: {a: bool; n?: number; s?: string;};

opts = {a: true, n: 2};     // Ok
opts = {a: true, s: 'x'};   // Ok
opts = {a: true};         // Ok
opts = {a: true,z: 3};     // Ok
opts = {}; // not ok
opts = {z: 3}; // not ok
```

So this means an object is considered a sub-type of another object if it supports *at least* the required properties.

That deals with setting the object. Now if you consider using the object you'll see where the power lies. Because the type promises only `n` and `s` (and `a` in my example), the code calling properties on `n` can only ask for these properties. The additional properties cannot be accessed:

```
var opts: {a: bool; n?: number; s?: string;};

opts = {a: true, n: 1, s: 'Hi', z: 3};

var x - opts.z; // not ok
```

So we still have type safety, because we can only *use* the properties in the type declaration - not the additional properties.

Comment: "so any object is compatible with this type"

Not exactly. The type will still require that if the `n` property is present, it must be of type `number`, for example.